# Deleting Logic Apps with PowerShell iteratively

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-logic-apps

I have created 20+ logic apps with RM template, but I would like to remove them. Is there a PowerShell approach feasible to fetch logic apps under a resource group name and delete iteratively.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should be able to do this with the following pipeline and may add additional filters to it.
As soon as you see the correct set of Logic Apps being processed, just remove the `-WhatIf`.

```
Login-AzureRmAccount
Get-AzureRmResource -ResourceGroupName 'yourGroupName' -ResourceType 'Microsoft.Logic/workflows' | Remove-AzureRmResource -WhatIf
```